# Ng-show shows div no matter what

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Okay so what I'm trying to do is the following: if the input called `'autoPack'` is empty, show the `div` `'forma_reservas_gustos'`. If it is not empty, do NOT show the `div`. The problem I'm having is that no matter what the value from the `input` is, the `div` is always displayed. I've tried so many things but nothing seems to be working.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="autoPack" id="autoPack" ng-model="autoPack" value="">

<div class="forma_reservas_gustos" ng-show="!autoPack">
  <div class="forma_reservas_gustos_interior wid1k pbot20">
    <div class="paso">
      <div class="butpasos">
        <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/uno.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="textpasos">
        <h3>SELECCIONA EL PACK DE EXPERIENCIAS QUE MÁS TE GUSTE</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    [...]
```

JS

```
document.forms["forma_reservas_form"].autoPack.value = "xxxx";
```

When I inspect it with Google Developer Tools, the html `input` does have the value `'xxxx'`. So it is in fact not empty, therefore the `div` should not be displayed yet it is for some strange reason. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `autoPack` should be a property of `$scope`...not just a property on a form.  can you show your controller code?

Comment: ng-show="autoPack.length == 0" does not work either. It then never shows the div, even if it is empty. :S

Comment: Omg you're right Steve I had completely forgotten about the controller... it works now! thanks!!!

Comment: @SteveDanner Consider answering the question so it doesn't appear unanswered anymore. Or OP can answer it himself.

Comment: @JustinJmnz, good call.  Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `autoPack` needs to be a property of `$scope`...not just a property on the form.

```
...
$scope.autoPack = "xxxx";
...
```